# JavaScript - Computed properties - deep confusion

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, computed-properties

Seems I am quite confused by computed properties in JavaScript.

When I define an object and I put `[d]` as a key (as a property key/name) what does this `[d]` actually do? Seems that for some values `d` it calculates `s = d.toString()` and uses that value `s` as the property key. 
But for other values `d` (e.g. when `d` is a symbol) it uses really the symbol's value as the key.

So this dual behavior of `[d]` (as a syntax construct) seems confusing. Could someone explain in depth how this works?

Are there other special cases btw? Or is it just when `d` is a Symbol when we have that special behavior?

Back to the basics: what **things** can be keys/names of properties of an object? Is it just strings or just strings and symbols or is there also something additional... ?

Example:

```js
var symbol = Symbol("test");

function Animal(name){
 this.name = name;
}

Animal.prototype = {};
Animal.prototype.constructor = Animal;

function Dog(breed){
    this.breed = breed;
    this.name = "Dog";
    this.s = symbol;
}

Dog.prototype = new Animal();
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog;

console.log("001");
var d = new Dog("Sharo");
for (let x in d){
    console.log(x, ":", d[x]);
}

console.log("002");
d = new Object();
for (let x in d){
    console.log(x, ":", d[x]);
}

console.log("003");
d = new Number(5);
for (let x in d){
    console.log(x, ":", d[x]);
}

var d1 = {};
var d2 = {};

var d = new Dog("Sharo");

var m = {[d1] : 5, [d2] : 10, [d] : 20, z : 100, symbol: 2000, [symbol] : 5000};

console.log("============================");
console.log(m);

for (let x in m){
    console.log(x, ":", m[x]);
}
console.log("============================");
```

Comment: Have you read e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors? *"Property names are string or Symbol. Any other value, including a number, is coerced to a string."*

Comment: @jonrsharpe No, I haven't... Only books (some of them 15 years ago when there were no Symbols at all)... And some of them (even though recent) consider this info too basic and just skip to mention `Symbol`. They just talk about property names and it's natural to assume that names are strings and strings only. That's what caused my confusion. This link seems to be exactly what I need! Thanks.

Comment: Read the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/): [12.2.6.8 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation -> ComputedPropertyName -> Step 2](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation) -> [6.2.3.1 GetValue (V) -> Step 5.a.ii](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-getvalue) -> [7.1.13 ToObject ( argument )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toobject)

Comment: @jonrsharpe "Property names are string or Symbol. Any other value, including a number, is coerced to a string." How are they coerced? By calling `toString()` as I guessed or... in some other way?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks. Did you mean to point me to `ToPropertyKey` instead or...?

Comment: Why a Symbol stays a symbol and anything else is converted to a string? [12.2.6.8 Runtime Semantics: Evaluation -> ComputedPropertyName](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-initializer-runtime-semantics-evaluation) -> Step 4 -> [7.1.14 ToPropertyKey ( argument )](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-topropertykey) -> Step 3 + 4

Comment: @Andreas Yeah, I saw it, it's right below `ToObject` to which you pointed me first. Thanks again.

Comment: My first comment was for: _"Could someone explain in depth how this works? Are there other special cases btw?"_, and the second for: _"Is it just strings or just strings and symbols or is there also something additional... ?"_

Comment: @Andreas OK... I see... Never mind... I think I get it now.

Comment: @peter.petrov as far i know, the computed property value will work against's an object's key, and, the value of the key must be of type string or a number, not other thing. So basically javascript, behind the covers, will attemp to map the <whatever-value> (Regardles their type) into a string or a number in order to be a compatible key value for an object. That is the end of the history.. now, how it happens, i guess that for Symbols the map is straightfoward, for others things i guess the .toString() method is applied to that thing. For me this is totally valid question, upvoted btw.

Comment: @Victor - *"and, the value of the key must be of type string or a number, not other thing"* No, that's incorrect. Object property keys are never numbers. They can be strings or Symbols. Details in the answers below.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, i'm not expert in javascript.. but in Chrome, as far i can code, i can actually see keys as numbers. Allow me share my point with this image: https://imgbbb.com/image/L4PBKi (see on the bottom, the chrome's console, the lines of code i wrote and gets evaluated by the interpreter).

Comment: @Victor - That's just how devtools is showing it to you, because you're allowed to use numeric literals as key names in object literals -- but the resulting property key is a string. Try this: ```for (const key in {1:1}) { console.log(`${key}: ${typeof key}`); }``` (And, again, see the answers below, which refer to relevant parts of the specification.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder whoa!! you were right... and thanks for taking the time (and the patience) for pointing that out. BTW: i upvoted your answer previously (for now, the only one.. definitively it deserve more upvotes ) https://imgbbb.com/image/L4PIlH

Comment: @Victor - My pleasure. :-) If you're interested in the new things being added to JavaScript, I have a book coming out early next year -- links in my profile. :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no one seems interested in answering this question I will answer it myself based on the comments which I got above, and due to which I am not confused anymore.

Note that this answer here is **ES6** based. I mean... who knows what else the JavaScript future will hold :)

> When I define an object and I put `[d]` as a key (as a property key/name) what does this `[d]` actually do? Seems that for some objects `d` it calculates `s = d.toString()` and uses that value `s` as the property key. But for other objects `d` (e.g. when `d` is a Symbol) it uses really the Symbol's value as the key.

Yes, that's correct. When d is a Symbol its value is used directly. When d is anything but Symbol its value is coerced to a string and that string is used as the property name/key. The coercion is more like `String(d)` rather than `d.toString()`.

> So this dual behavior of `[d]` (as a syntax construct) seems confusing. Could someone explain in depth how this works?

Already explained above.

> Are there other special cases btw? Or is it just when `d` is a Symbol when we have that special behavior?

There are no other "special cases". As of ES6 only strings and symbols can be property keys.

> Back to the basics: what **things** can be keys/names of properties of an object? Is it just strings or just strings and symbols or is there also something additional... ?

As already said, as of ES6 only strings and symbols can be property keys.

**References:**

(1) 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

"Property names are string or Symbol. Any other value, including a number, is coerced to a string."

(2)
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-topropertykey

Comment: @Andreas Good idea. Done.

Comment: How about a function as key? `const m = new Map(); const p = (x) => console.log(x); m.set(p, "test"); for ([key, value] of m) { key(value); key(1); }`

Answer (score 2):

In a comment on another answer you said you thought property keys were always strings. They *were*, until ES2015. :-)

> So this dual behavior of `[d]` (as a syntax construct) seems confusing. Could someone explain in depth how this works?

As of ES2015, Symbols were added to the language, and object property keys became able to be either strings or Symbols. So when you do:

```
const obj = {
    [d]: "foo"
};
```

...the computed property key (`[d]: "foo"`) part of that works like this:

1. Let `value` be the result of evaluating the expression `"foo"`
2. Let `keyValue` be the result of evaluating the expression `d`
3. If `keyValue` is a Symbol, let `key` = `keyValue`; otherwise, let `key` = `String(keyValue)`
4. Set the property `key` on `obj` to the value `value`

I've left out a couple of details in there for clarity. You can see that in the [ToPropertyKey](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-topropertykey) abstract operation in the specification, which is used whenever a value is used as a property key (in an object literal as above, or when accessing an object property via brackets notation, etc.).

> Are there other special cases btw? Or is it just when d is a Symbol when we have that special behavior?
>
> Back to the basics: what things can be keys/names of properties of an object? Is it just strings or just strings and symbols or is there also something additional... ?

Just Symbol and string. :-) It's not so much that Symbol is a *special case*, it's just that where it used to be that property keys were always strings, now they can be strings *or* Symbols.

(Fun fact: In the spec, [they define](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-type) "property key" as the string or Symbol that identifies a property, and "property name" as a property key that's a string. But don't rely on it, the spec itself is a bit inconsistent, and the `Object.keys` method — which returns an array of property *names*, not property *keys* — existed before that terminology was added in ES2015. And then they added a `keys` method to arrays that returns an iterator of *numbers* [the [indexes](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-type) in the array]. Fun fun fun... :-) )

All ES5 and earlier operations that returned or looped over property names were specified in ES2015 to ignore Symbol-keyed properties. So `for-in`, `Object.keys`, `Object.getOwnPropertyNames` all only look at the string-keyed properties. ES2015 added `Reflect.ownKeys` (which includes both strings and Symbols) and `Object.getOwnPropertySymbols` (which includes only own, Symbol-keyed properties).

---

Side note:

> Seems that for some objects d it calculates s = d.toString() and uses that value s as the property key...

Not just objects, and it's more like `String(d)` (although if `d` is an object it comes to the same thing). Anything that isn't string or Symbol is converted to string.

> ...But for other objects d (e.g. when d is a Symbol) it uses really the Symbol's value as the key.

Symbols aren't objects, Symbol is a primitive type. But yes, if the property key is a Symbol, it's used directly, not converted to string.

Comment: Thanks a lot again... The 2 side notes are also very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd test out a minor point from [TJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59437056/5134722):

> [I]t's more like String(d) (although if d is an object it comes to the same thing)

```
sessionStorage.setItem("secret", "sssh!");

const evilObject = {
  toString() {
    console.log("I stole a secret: " + sessionStorage.getItem("secret"));
    return "InnocentPropertyName";
  }
};

const obj = {
  [evilObject]: "Hello! I'm the property's value."
}

console.log(obj.InnocentPropertyName)
```

If you check the console after this you end up with:

```
I stole a secret: sssh!
Hello! I'm the property's value.
```

Conclusion: If `toString()` is defined on a non-string object, and you pass it to the computed property square bracket operator, then `toString()` will be called when setting up that property. Furthermore, said `toString()` may have side-effects, and potentially evil ones at that, as demonstrated.

**Key security aside:** If you are creating properties using this operator, make sure you trust whatever you put into it. That applies even if you think what you're putting in is a string. If you got that "string" from elsewhere, can you be really sure it's a string? If you expect a string, then sanitize it: do a dynamic test for the string type before using it.